# I am trying to add a new line (row) but instead it modifies the existing one in sql xml

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2012

I am trying to add a new line (row) but instead it modifies the existing one

```
DECLARE @parXML         XML
       ,@subunitate     CHAR(9)
       ,@tip            CHAR(2)
       ,@numar          CHAR(8)
       ,@pvaluta        DECIMAL(9 ,2)
       ,@cod            CHAR(9)
       ,@cantitate      INT
       ,@subtip         CHAR(2)


SELECT @subunitate = @parXML.value('(/row/@subunitate)[1]' ,'varchar(9)')
      ,@tip       = @parXML.value('(/row/@tip)[1]' ,'char(2)')
      ,@numar     = @parXML.value('(/row/@numar)[1]' ,'char(8)')
      ,@cod       = 'TVA 473.04'



IF @parXML.value('(/row/row/@cod)[1]' ,'char(9)') IS NOT NULL
    SET @parXML.modify(
            'replace value of (/row/row/@cod)[1] with sql:variable("@cod")'
        )
ELSE
    SET @parXML.modify (
            'insert attribute cod{sql:variable("@cod")} into (/row/row)[1]'
        )
```

Comment: what is the value of `@parXML` here?

Comment: You can check like below and take decision as required - 
`IF @X.exist('/row/row/@cod') = 1`